# Komodo Code Browser activation?

Tags: browser, panels, komodo

Working with Komodo 8.5.x , how does one use "Code Browser" for open files ?

I get an error that says something like: 
"Could not find a node corresponding to the scope at filename.js##### in the Code Browser".

Comment: Note that the Code Browser is just showing you code for the currently opened files, it is not an alternative view for the "Open Files" pane.

Answer (score 0):

> Just figured it out.
>   The files have to be opened via the 'Places' button in the left pane (default position).
>
> -Then Classes, Variables, and Events are listed in series ( at least for Javascript ) in the 'Code Browser' pane.